# Number of entries per month

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have something similar to the following situation, probably not the best example but somewhat similar to what I really have. Let's say I have 4 tables that due to certain circumstances I can't change.

```
CREATE TABLE [Hospital] ( 
[HospitalID] INT IDENTITY NOT NULL,
[HospitalName] VARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL 
);
CREATE TABLE [Doctors] (
    [DoctorID] INT IDENTITY NOT NULL , 
    [HospitalID] INT NOT NULL,
    [DoctorName] VARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE [Patient] (
[PatientID] INT IDENTITY NOT NULL , 
[DoctorID] INT NOT NULL
); 
CREATE TABLE [PatientAppointment] ( 
[PatientID] INT IDENTITY NOT NULL, 
[Date] DATETIME NOT NULL
);
```

I want to write a stored procedure that get's a year and a month as parameters and it is supposed to return [HospitalName] , [DoctorsName] and the number of patient appointments for that time period. 
This is what I have now and I am stuck

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Procedure]
    @year INT , 
    @month INT 
AS
    SELECT COUNT([Date]) AS NumberOfAppointments FROM [PatientAppointment]
    WHERE MONTH([Date]) = @month AND YEAR([Date]) = @year
    SELECT [Hospital].HospitalName , [Doctors].DoctorName FROM [Doctors]
    INNER JOIN [Hospital] ON [Hospital].HospitalID = [Doctors].DoctorID 

RETURN 0
```

I can't figure out how to extract the info I need and I am limited to one stored procedure. [image: supposed answer of the procedure]

Comment: Lots of problems with this table structure, why is the patientid in the patient appointment table an identity field?  it should have an apptid field and the patient id should be a key to the other table. You should also split the doctor and the hospital connection to a separate table so you don't have duplicate information.  For this sample its small enough, but later on you should normalize the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Procedure]
    @year INT , 
    @month INT 
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT h.HospitalId, d.DoctorName, count(p.PatientId) as NumberOfAppointments
    FROM Hospital h
    INNER JOIN Doctors d
    ON h.HospitalId = d.HospitalId
    INNER JOIN Patient p
    ON d.DoctorId = p.DoctorId
    INNER JOIN PatientAppointment ap
    ON p.PatientId = ap.PatientId
    AND MONTH(ap.[Date]) = @month
    AND YEAR(ap.[Date]) = @year
    GROUP BY h.HospitalId, d.DoctorName
END
```

Answer (score 1):

My answer is very similar to the one posted by Joachim but there is one VERY significant difference. This code is SARGable where the original query and the fine example already posted are not. Since you say you can't change the table structure I will refrain from suggesting changes....although you could greatly improve on these structures.

```
Create Procedure dbo.SomeBetterName
(
    @Date date
) AS
    select h.HospitalName
        , d.DoctorName
        , COUNT(pa.[Date]) as NumAppointments
    from Hospital h
    join Doctors d on h.HospitalID = d.HospitalID
    join Patient p on p.DoctorID = d.DoctorID
    join PatientAppointment pa on pa.PatientID = p.PatientID
    where pa.Date >= dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, @Date), 0)
        and pa.Date < dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, @Date) + 1, 0)
    group by h.HospitalName
        , d.DoctorName
```